# use GET and POST arrays with variable names in PHP

Tags: php, http

I'm struggling with variable variables in PHP.
I have the following piece of code.

```
if($_GET["action"] == 1){
        $action = "_GET";
    }else{
        $action = "_POST";
}
...
${$action["lang_id"]}
```

I get the following errors:

- Illegal string offset "lang_id" (but if I use directly the $_GET name it works properly)
- udefined variable _ (yes, an underscore).

thanks in advance

Comment: You are assigning $action, the string "_GET" and then applying an array action

Comment: use `$_REQUEST['lang_id']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> ${$action["lang_id"]}
> ```

Remember that the variable name goes between `${` and `}`, and that the variable name you are looking for is `_GET` or `_POST`.

You are trying to get the value of `$action["lang_id"]` and use that as the variable name… but `$action` is a string.

You need to use `$action` as the variable name and then read the property from the result.

```
${$action}["lang_id"]
```

… but you would probably be better off using `$_REQUEST` instead of variable variables. (Watch out for cookies with the same name as post or query string data though).

Comment: How did you work out that that is what they want to do? The check for $_GET["action"] throws me off

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea — I glanced at it and it seemed obvious. (Perhaps you are confused by `$_GET` being populated with query string data for any request and not something that is restricted to GET requests. Many people appear to have been tripped up by this poor choice of name for the variable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$_REQUEST**.

$_REQUEST is just combination of both $_GET and $_POST.

It works for both above two global variables.

So simply use `$_REQUEST['lang_id']`

Comment: "$_REQUEST is just combination of both $_GET and $_POST" — "just"? No, not just. It is those **and** $_COOKIE.